# How to fix repeating content on top of a background image?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a background image with a navbar and some content on top of it. What is happening is the navbar and related content that is inside the bgimg div is repeating on top of the background image which covers the entire screen.

```
    <div class="bgimg">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1" style="margin-left: 5%">
          <span class="w-100 d-lg-none d-block"></span>
          <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">Home</a>
          <div class="w-100 text-right">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar7">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1 text-right" id="myNavbar7" style="margin-right: 5%">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-nowrap">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a routerLink="/software" class="nav-link">Software</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a routerLink="/about" class="nav-link">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a routerLink="/contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="myName">
          <span>blah</span>
          <div class="description">
            <span>Developer</span>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    .bgimg {
        background: url("/assets/images/DSC01250.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .myName {
        font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
        margin-top: 300px; //half page height
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .description {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
```

I would just like one background image that covers the screen with no repeating content on top of it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code in your question isn't complete/minimal to see what you are asking. Please update the question, including putting in a link to a test image - instead of your relative path image - so we can see it. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a position: fixed; attribute and adding a width and height attribute to hold all divs true to their parent container.